# Cannot find Login submenu from Context menu by using Windows Automation

Tags: wpf, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to automate login and file download from an application. I could login by getting the Menu item (on the toolbar) and expanding it and selecting the 'logon' menu item in the submenu. I got the submenu by using FindFirst on the Desktop AutomationElement for the 'Context'. On using FindFirst for the logon menu Item I am able to get the login child window. The issue comes after login when I need to 'click' on the Menu Item 'Task' on the toolbar, get the Submenu from the 'Context' and select the 'download file' from the submenu. I cannot find this Context from the Desktop Automation Element. Using Inspect tool, I see that context menu is child of Context Window which has no parent. shouldnt all AutomationElements/Windows be children of Desktop AE ??? If I mimic 'mouse Click' on Task menu item, Can I get the sub menu launched using Win32 GetMenu or GetSubmenu call? Is there an example that will explain that?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will ever be able to automate login and password prompt (Ctrl-Alt-Del) as Windows is preventing you from doing this for security reasons.

Comment: So the Login part was done without any issues. An update to the issue I mentioned in the post. The entry in the Sub menu is titled 'System' and I can get to it by searching it on the 'Context' menu about 50% of the time. Reason is that the application Window itself has a 'System' Menu (you can get to it by clicking on the icon next to the Titlebar). Now I need to know how to differentiate those 2 System Menu Items, since both end up being on the Context menu.